# SQL Query: finding cheapest car by company

Tags: sql, postgresql

Following YouTube tutorial "Learn PostgreSQL Tutorial - Full Course for Beginners", I replicate teacher's code but yields different result and cannot figure out why.

Table is this simple:

```
 id  |    make    |    model     |   price
-----+------------+--------------+------------
   1 | Toyota     | Matrix       | 25451.36
```

and so on, 1000 entries.

Querying cheapest model from manufacturer, tutorial says:

```
SELECT  
       make, model, MIN(price) 
   FROM 
       car 
   GROUP BY 
        make, model;
```

And it works properly, returning as many entries as distinct car makers.
But when I run it in my PostgreSQL terminal returns all 1000 entries disordered.

However, when I query without model's name, I get the right answer, but (obviously)
without the model name as shown below:

```
    make       | cheapest
---------------+----------
 Fillmore      | 72263.48
 McLaren       | 78510.84
```

Any suggestions as to why this might happen?

Comment: Please add second query.  What were you expecting instead?

Comment: Maybe all model is different with or without make column.

Comment: Second query is as described: SELECT make, MIN(price) FROM car GROUP BY make;

Comment: @doctorgu That is actually the case, but then again, why does yield different results from the tutorial when we are using same table, same DB, same everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xbbgRLhTwTuZTERrwJo1Mj/0) works as expected. Notice the output. It shows a proper `GROUP BY`.

Query source:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    make   varchar(40),
    model  varchar(40),
    price  integer
);

INSERT INTO t (make, model, price) VALUES
    ('Fillmore', 'F_M1', 10000),
    ('Fillmore', 'F_M2', 20000),
    ('McLaren', 'M_M2', 40000),
    ('McLaren', 'M_M2', 60000),
    ('Toyota', 'T_M1', 12000),
    ('Toyota', 'T_M2', 24000),
    ('Toyota', 'T_M3', 48000);

SELECT  
       make, model, MIN(price) 
   FROM 
       t 
   GROUP BY 
        make, model
   ORDER BY make, model;
```

Result:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    make   varchar(40),
    model  varchar(40),
    price  integer
);

INSERT INTO t (make, model, price) VALUES
    ('Fillmore', 'F_M1', 10000),
    ('Fillmore', 'F_M2', 20000),
    ('McLaren', 'M_M2', 40000),
    ('McLaren', 'M_M2', 60000),
    ('Toyota', 'T_M1', 12000),
    ('Toyota', 'T_M2', 24000),
    ('Toyota', 'T_M3', 48000);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT  
       make, model, MIN(price) 
   FROM 
       t 
   GROUP BY 
        make, model
   ORDER BY make, model;
```

| make | model | min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fillmore | F_M1 | 10000 |
| Fillmore | F_M2 | 20000 |
| McLaren | M_M2 | 40000 |
| Toyota | T_M1 | 12000 |
| Toyota | T_M2 | 24000 |
| Toyota | T_M3 | 48000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xbbgRLhTwTuZTERrwJo1Mj/0)